# How to prepend text to a file as an npm script command

Tags: package.json, npm-scripts

I'm writing a bookmarklet. I need to prepend `"javascript:"` to the compiled, minified JavaScript. I'm looking for a way to accomplish this using an NPM `package.json` script.

```
{ 
    "scripts": {
        "oar:transpile-typescript": "tsc --target es6  --lib dom,es6 ./OarBookmarklet/Oar.ts",
        "oar:minify-javascript": "jsmin -o ./OarBookmarklet/oar.min.js ./OarBookmarklet/oar.js",
        "oar:prepend-javascript": "[??? prepend `javascript:` to minified JavaScript ???]",
        "oar": "run-s oar:transpile-typescript oar:minify-javascript oar:prepend-javascript",
        "build": "run-s oar"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is running on something Unix-like then:

```
(printf 'javascript:' ; cat ./OarBookmarklet/oar.min.js) > ./OarBookmarklet/oar.bm.min.js
```

should do the job.

---

**Edit in response to OP's comment**:

> My execution environment is Windows, ...

In that case you should be able to use:

```
(set /p junk="javascript:" <nul & type ./OarBookmarklet/oar.min.js) > ./OarBookmarklet/oar.bm.min.js
```

The `set /p ... <nul` weirdness is a way to get some text sent to stdout without a newline being appended to it.

Comment: My execution environment is Windows, VS Code, PowerShell console.

Comment: I had to use double-backslashes for the path: `"(set /p junk=\"javascript:\" <nul & type .\\OarBookmarklet\\oar.min.js) > .\\OarBookmarklet\\oar.bm.min.js"`

Comment: Is is possible to prepend the text to the original `oar.min.js` without having to create another file, i.e. `oar.bm.min.js` ?

Answer (score 2):

For a cross-platform solution utilize node.js and it's builtin [`fs.readFileSync(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) and [`fs.writeFileSync(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options). This way it doesn't matter which shell your npm script runs in (`sh`, `cmd.exe`, `bash`, `bash.exe`, `pwsh`, `...` )

To achieve this consider either of the following two solutions - they're essentially the same just different methods of application.

---

#### Solution A. Using a separate node.js script

Create the following script, lets save it as *prepend.js* in the root of the project directory, i.e. at the same level as where *package.json* resides.

**prepend.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const filepath = './OarBookmarklet/oar.min.js';
const data = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
fs.writeFileSync(filepath, 'javascript:' + data);
```

**package.json**

Define the `oar:prepend-javascript` npm script in *package.json* as follows::

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "oar:prepend-javascript": "node prepend",
  ...
},
```

<sub>**Note:** Above node.js invokes the script and performs the required task. If you choose to save *prepend.js* in a different directory than the aforementioned then ensure you define the correct path to it, i.e. `"oar:prepend-javascript": "node ./some/other/path/to/prepend.js"`</sub>

---

#### Solution B. Inline the node.js script in package.json

Alternatively, you can inline the content of *prepend.js* in your npm script, therefore negating the use of a separate `.js` file.

**package.json**

Define the `oar:prepend-javascript` script in *package.json* as follows:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "oar:prepend-javascript": "node -e \"const fs = require('fs'); const fp = './OarBookmarklet/oar.min.js'; const d = fs.readFileSync(fp); fs.writeFileSync(fp, 'javascript:' + d);\""
  ...
},
```

<sub>**Note:** Here the nodejs command line option [`-e`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script) is utilized to evaluate the inline JavaScript.</sub>